# Are we allowed to post videos here for your music to be critiqued?

Tags: discussion

Are we allowed to post a link for a youtube video here and ask for feedback?

Comment: Oh yeah, you can also post a link in the chat room: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/440/the-practice-room and ask if people want to listen and comment.

Comment: For a more complete list of things you can or cannot ask, you can always look at the help center!

Answer (score 9):

Not on the site itself, no. That is not what this site is for. However, once you have earned a couple of upvotes on a question or answer you will be able to use our [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/440/the-practice-room) room, where quite a few folks post music or videos.